# Iterating generic list using indexes (C#)

Tags: c#, list, generics

I've pretty much switched over to generic types and away from the array types but now and then I need to iterate through something where it is convenient to have indexes like those arrays provide. Generic lists are great because they keep the order of things internally the same as the order of things inserted, they grow dynamically and come with very useful methods but can I jump around like I can with arrays? Could I say, iterate a generic list using a for loop and on certain indexes get the value of past or future indexes without having to iterate over all of the values in between?

Example using an array:

```
for (int i = 50; i != 0; --i)
{
    if (myArray[i] == 1 && i + 5 <= 50)
    {
        myArray[i + 5] = myArray[i + 5] + 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do that with list just like arrays.  List have indexers which act similar to array indexer.  Did you try it and it not work?

```
var lists = Enumerable.Range(0, 51).ToList();
for (var i = 50; i != 0; --i)
{
    if (lists[i] == 1 && i + 5 <= 50)
    {
        lists[i + 5] = lists[i + 5] + 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't try it because I had no idea it was possible. I've only foreach-ed lists so far and it has always been enough until now. So, generic lists have the same size restrictions (Int32.MaxValue)?

Comment: Can I achieve this without using the System.Linq namespace? It feels like this should be in the System.Collections.Generic namespace. I don't have use for any of the types in System.Core.dll so it seems like a waste to load it just for this one thing.

Comment: You're only using `System.Linq` for the `Enumerable.Range` call, not for the actual iteration. Also, you'll find it hard to write any reasonable amount of code without `System.Core.dll`, so you might as well go ahead and load it.

Comment: I realised that. What can I use instead of Enumerable.Range?

Comment: Enumberable.Range and ToList was just a simple way for me to create a list that contained 51 elements.  You can still do a var lists = new List<int>(51); and fill them in by hand or whatever you had before to create the list.  That really had nothing to do with the solution.

Comment: So you can use the () in the instantiation. I've left it empty so many times I didn't even think it had any use, other than to be left empty. I assume that if you exceed the value an exception will be thrown.

Comment: The int in the constructor of the list is more about it knowing ahead of time how much memory to allocate vs doing it dynamically each time you add.  It will be initialized to the default so with list<int>(51) the list would contain 51 zeros.